# Logstash preventing application from rotating logs

Tags: logging, logstash, logstash-file

I have a application running in vagrant VM and log files are shared with host machine using synced folder. I am trying to add these logs in logstash from host directory to another VM that is running logstash. Everything works fine until application tries to rotate log files at midnight. It throws file in use error and crashes. Is there any solution of this problem?

Comment: are you using the file input in logstash? what logger are you using in your application? i´ve seen several problems when the logging framework is not properly handling the inodes when rotating.

Comment: Yes, I am using File input in logstash. I am using python logging module and generating custom logs